# CanvasJS - how to insert value on the specific X-axis position?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, canvasjs

I would like to ask how can I insert value on the specific X-axis position?

For example:

I have 10 markers (labels) which are displayed at bottom of the X-axis
I have 100 values with (x-axis-coords where to placed and their value for axis-y)  which need to be inserted on the specific
position in the X-axis.
This means that one marker is not corresponding to one value. Should be independent.

How can i do it using the CanvasJS or any other library please?

Answer (score 0):

@redrom,

Label on X axis is either user defined “label” or x value at that point.

If you have 100 [dataPoints](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/) and like to show up labels only for 10 dataPoints, you can set interval to 10 so that for every 10th dataPoint labels will be shown.

Check this example.

```js
var dps = [];
var yVal = 50;

for( var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
 yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));  
    dps.push({x: i, y: yVal, label: "xValue: " +i});
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
 axisX:{
   interval: 10//change this to 20 and observe X-Axis labels
  },
 data: [
 {
  type: "line",
  dataPoints: dps
 }     
 ]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```